# How can I delete custom attribute in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2.1.0

I have created an attribute which was showing error while adding product, now I have uninstalled and deleted the module still error is there , How to erase that attribute from table.

Comment: you can directly delete those entry from eav_attribute table

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete attribute from database.

Search your attribute code in column `attribute_code` in `eav_attribute` table.

Delete your attribute from here.

Comment: what is the command to delete it am not only able to access db from putty

Comment: @S H Patel  am using this query not affection even not running DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id 161

Comment: Have you C-Panel details ?

Comment: Yes I am having

Comment: You can open database from there, search and delete from there directly.

Comment: Success or not ?

Comment: I think it may show errors again so want to delete by program

Comment: Delete var folder and check again. attribute muse be delete from database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48122/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-supriya-mishra).